# Optimal setup with Categorical/Discrete data using Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, categorical-data, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, discrete-data

I need to implement a neural network whose dataset and response are composed of only 0,1, -1 values. For those with experience, which setup would you recommend (activation function, loss, neurons, etc)? I haven't found much in the literature on dealing with categorical variables

Comment: Why does it have to be a neural network? And are the categories (-1, 0, 1) meaningfully ordered, or is that just how they've been encoded?

Comment: Categories (-1, 0, 1) are meaningfully ordered

Answer (score 0):

The number of input and hidden neurons depends on how many input features you have.  Activation functions used at the hidden layer could be either tanh or logistic, and probably linear activation on the output side.  ANNs do like input features whose range is [-1,1].

I would start by using multiple linear regression, however, with a single dependent variable based on your -1, 0, and +1 values.  The predicted output for each object would be assigned to +1 if $\hat{y}_i > 0.33$, 0 if  $-0.33 < \hat{y}_i \leq 0.33$, and -1 if  $\hat{y}_i \leq -0.33$.